# Finding Clusters in Arbitrage Sites

Tags: clustering

I'm much more of a computer scientist than a statistician, so this question is a bit far from my area of expertise, but should fit in here.

Suppose I have a video game where there are ten cities or so that the player can visit with a ship. Each city sells and buys goods, with the goods being the same everywhere, but their price changing by city and each city selling goods for more than they're buying them.

Imagine that the player occasionally writes two lists, one with the list of cities where a good G is being sold for the lowest price and one where that good is bought for the highest price. This is essentially a record of maximally profitable arbitrage opportunities.

Suppose I want to take that record and cluster the cities based on how similar their prices are to each other. Is there some special type of clustering method that is perfect for this scenario or should I just fiddle with a k-means clustering until I get good-looking results?

Edit:

Here's some sample data.

```
{'low_ask' : 3.15, 'low_cities' : ['A', 'B'], 'high_bid': 3.23, 'high_cities': ['E', 'F'], 'product': 'pineapples'}
{'low_ask' : 9.82, 'low_cities' : ['D'], 'high_bid': 9.97, 'high_cities': ['B', 'C'], 'product': 'cigars'}
```

This would mean that the cheapest place to buy cigars and pineapples is for 3.15 and 9.82 from the low_cities listed and the best place to sell them would be for 3.23 and 9.97 from the high_cities listed. I have a few dozen maybe a few hundred of these datapoints.

Comment: I don't quite understand what data you have available for this. Is it just the mentioned lists, i.e., information about the cities depends on what players mention them how often, particularly implying that there may be far more data for some cities than for others, and that information about the cities' prices is quite incomplete?

Comment: The data's reasonably complete since I wrote a computer program to record it for me. The data is in a dict with four members, {'low_ask' : 3.15, 'low_cities' : ['A', 'B'], 'high_bid': 3.23, 'high_cities': ['E', 'F']} means that the lowest price to buy is 3.15 at cities A and B with the highest price to sell is to cities E and F at 3.23. I'll edit this into the question immediately.

Comment: Can you also give us an idea how the information is "distributed" over the cities and goods, i.e., whether all cities have more or less the same amount of information for all goods, or whether there are missing city/good combinations, or some with only one or two indications? I assume the players' indications are reliable, i.e., every entry should be trusted? This is non-standard, as the cities to be clustered are not in themselves "data points". Also there is some subtle implied information (namely that not mentioned cities are between highest and lowest).

Comment: The way I'd probably go on about this is to try to construct a reasonable dissimilarity measure between cities and then use some dissimilarity-based clustering such as PAM or average linkage, probably aided by an MDS plot. Once you have the dissimilarity it can be standard. Designing this is the key issue here in my view.

Comment: @Lewian: Player indications are reliable in that sense, but the cities don't always buy/sell every good. It's intermittent though. I'll look into dissimilarity-based clustering if that's what you recommend.